# how to get the gluon Android plugins or .jar: magnetometer, compass, display, position?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, accelerometer, javafxports, gluon-mobile

For installing a component in Eclipse Neon, we usually add a plugin or a .jar
Or, in case of these plugins for Android, I don't understand how to do?

In the Eclipse Marketplace, I don't see these plugins.

Where can I get them?

My configuration:
Eclispe Neon 2

My Build gradle (some items):

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.2'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.1.0'    
    }

    jfxmobile {
        downConfig {
            version '4.0.0'
            plugins 'accelerometer', 'compass', 'device', 'orientation', 'storage', 'vibration', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'position'
        }

android {
    compileSdkVersion = '23'
    buildToolsVersion = '25.0.1'
    androidSdk = 'C:/Users/pascal/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The current version for the plugins is 3.2.0. The jfxmobile plugin will manage to download the plugins and their platform versions.

Comment: OK. I have Gluon tools 2.4.0 including e(fx)eclipse IDE 2.3.0.  Do you mean that I only have to modify, in build gradle, the jfxmobile downconfig from 4.0.0 to 3.2.0? Nothing else to do (add a library, ...)? Moreover, in the java code, when I use  "Services.get(MagnetometerService.class).ifPresent(service -> {....", I must add which kind of import to use this plugin ? I have a little bit lost :) Thanks

Comment: The jfxmobile plugin will add the Down plugin jars for you, the core ones and the platform ones. Check the list of dependencies or the console (use `--info`) when you build the project. As for imports, obviously you will need to import just the classes you are using (`Services`, `MagnetometerService`, ...). Note that you will have the jar with them, as any other dependency.

Comment: José, could you illustrate your explanation with an example like accelerometer by indicating * the URL for getting its jar file * how to import the class as you have mentioned it, whereas in  the Java Buid Path of my project, I can add this jar file, ... Thanks a lot for your help